# Dynamically generated buttons from XML always have the same attributes of the last node in XML file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, lambda

Using the below function, a series of buttons are generated into a flow layout panel based on an existing XML document.
The function is called at program load, and successfully generates buttons with different attributes, until they are clicked.
When the buttons are clicked, they should output it's attributes to a data grid view panel, but it only enters the attributes of the last node in the XML document.

```vb
Function loadMenuItems() As Double
    m_xmld = New XmlDocument
    m_xmld.Load("Menu.xml")
    m_nodelist = m_xmld.GetElementsByTagName("menuItems")
    For Each m_node In m_nodelist

        Dim newButton As New Button

        strID = m_node.Item("ID").InnerText

        strName = m_node.Item("Name").InnerText
        strPrice = m_node.Item("Price").InnerText
        strOptions = m_node.Item("Options").InnerText

        newButton.Name = "BTN_" & strID
        newButton.Width = 150
        newButton.Height = 150

        newButton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom
        newButton.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.TextAboveImage
        newButton.ForeColor = Color.White
        newButton.Text = strName


        AddHandler newButton.Click, Sub()
                                            DGV_Receipt.Rows.Add(strName, strOptions, strPrice)
                                        End Sub

        newButton.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(".\Resources\Icons\" & strName & ".png")


        FLP_Icons.Controls.Add(newButton)

    Next

End Function 'end the function definition.
```

The function being loaded:

```vb
Private Sub FORM_Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    loadMenuItems()
End Sub
```

I am a beginner at VB, so if I'm missing something obvious, please let me know!

Comment: Think you issue is down to the How you're extracting strName, strOptions,and strPrice in the addHandler.  Those values will be getting overwritten in your loop.  Think you're going to need to store them differently.  Either as extended button properties (Maybe encoded some way in Tag is enough) or store those values in a separate collection that you can lookup from based on which button was clicked

Comment: As an alternative to the answer, I think this would work if you either declare the three string variables within the loop (so that a different variable is captured by the closure each time) or maybe if you don't use the variables and instead use the reference to the xml inner text (I think later versions of .NET will re-create the iteration variable each pass through the loop so that you don't get surprising results when you capture it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the issue is your event handler. There is some nuance in how Lambda expressions work and you are running afoul of that.

One option would be to store the correct data in the `Tag` property, which is a general-purpose data field, of each `Button`, e.g.

```vb
newButton.Tag = {strName, strOptions, strPrice}
```

and then get the data back from the `Button` in the event handler:

```vb
AddHandler newButton.Click, Sub(sender, e)
                                Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
                                Dim data = DirectCast(btn.Tag, String())

                                DGV_Receipt.Rows.Add(data(0), data(1), data(2))
                            End Sub
```

Alternatively, define your own custom class that inherits `Button`, add dedicated properties for those values and then use them in your code. That custom class will work just like a regular `Button` but you can set those properties when you create it and then get the data back from them in the event handler.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to store these values in the Tag property, however when I tried implementing your code I had to replace `sender` with `newButton`.